# После отключения от Windows Server браузер Chrome начинает засыпать

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-server, tampermonkey

Есть Winows Server 2012. На нем установлен браузер Google Chrome. В браузере запущен userscript через tampermonkey.

Скрипт должен каждые 5 секунд (setinterval) выполнять какие-то действия.

Я оставляю запущенный браузер с открытой вкладкой (в которой запущен userscript) и просто отключаюсь от удаленного рабочего стола. И примерно через 10 минут перестает работать userscript.

Интересно что работотать он перестает постепенно, то есть setinterval как бы замедляеется. Изначально он установлен на 5 секунд, а уже через 10 минут после отключения от сервера он начинает срабатывать уже каждые 2 минуты, и так по нарастающей.

В настройках питания сервера я установил чтобы экран не отключался никогда.

Как обойти это? Мне нужно чтобы постоянно работал мой userscript на удаленном сервере. (скрипт подразумевает собой открытие произвольных сайтов через интервал времени).

Может быть посоветуете какой-то другой браузер в котором можно запустить userscript (javascript+jquery) и чтобы он не засыпал после отключения от удаленного рабочего стола.

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Напишите программку на C++, которая будет дергать вам мышку каждые 10 секунд :) Ну или можно привязать к мышке веревку, на веревку что-то легкое, веревку за окно - будет у вас мышка двигаться, браузер засыпать не будет. Но лучше всего... Переписать ваш userscript на headless браузере.

Comment: А если воспроизведение аудио на вкладку добавить?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [`Puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) безголовый браузер для эмуляции работы пользователя в браузере. Это что вам поможет решить задачу и разместить на любом `vds`/`vps` сервере

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko проще всего положить мышь на лежачий монитор который проигрывает видео. Вариант посложнее - на некоторых прозрачных полированных поверхностях мышь начинает сама "гулять", но я не могу точно сказать какая именно нужна поверхность - сталкивался.

Comment: @nick_n_a тоже рабочее решение с монитором, можно даже на тот же самый монитор мышку положить, в котором хром открыт ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хром замедляет таймеры в неактивных вкладках и при желании выгружает их из памяти. Вероятно он достаточно умный чтобы определить блокировку компа или отсутствие монитора и сделать то же самое.

Используй более подходящие средства, например, nodejs. Можно даже electron попробовать.

Comment: может быть есть более "глупый" браузер? в котором тоже можно запустить userscript или сделать свое расширение на javascript+jquery... где бы не замедлялись таймеры

Comment: @iKey такой браузер будет называться `Puppeteer`

Comment: @iKey, а если флаг headless передать хрому при запуске?

Comment: @Qwertiy а как это? Я запускаю его просто через ярлык?

Comment: @iKey, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Answer (score 0):

В целях економии ресурсов, Google Chrome приостанавливает вкладки, которые не используются.

Немного погуглив, набрел на вот такое расширение. Попробуйте, должно сработать:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok

Есть более оптимальные решения, но это должно быть самое простое.